# How can you place a back button onto a navigation bar between 2 ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4, segue, uistoryboard

I'm trying to create a transition between two scenes, this is a dumbed down version of what I have in my production code :

[image: 2 View controllers]

Both are `ViewController`, the left one has a TableView inside it and when clicked it should transition to the right hand scene, passing along data from whatever cell was clicked.

Currently, with a modal segue I can tap the cell and it transitions correctly, however, **I can't figure out how to place a back button onto the nav bar**.

I'm transitioning from the cell to the 2nd view controller like so :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSecond" sender:self];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecond"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Preparing segue for toSecond, setting some data on target scene");

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.theTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MyData * myData = [myDataArray objectAtIndex:path.row];

        // Obtain handles on the current and destination controllers
        FirstController * startingViewController;
        SecondController * destinationController;

        startingViewController = (FirstController * ) segue.sourceViewController;
        destinationController = (SecondController * ) segue.destinationViewController;

        destinationController.someData = myData;
    }
}
```

On the `SecondController`, I've tried amending the viewDidLoad method to programatically include a back button item as suggested in this previous SO question:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIBarButtonItem * back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                             target:nil 
                                                             action:nil];

    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:back];
}
```

So my question is, how can I get a back button onto that nav bar? Something like this :

[image: Desired back button]

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to add a back looking button to a modally presented ViewController easily

If you just want to add a normal button to the left side of the bar, do the following

```
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];

    UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
    item.leftBarButtonItem = rightButton;
    item.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [self.yourNavigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```

If you insist of presenting your view modally and still want a back button style you could use 
[Three20](http://three20.info/home#Style)

Answer (score 2):

One (easy) way, using the storyboard, is to embed a navigation controller into your view that has the table. Make sure the correct view, the one with the table, is highlighted and then go to Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.

The back button will automatically be there when you click a row of your table. Like Dan said, make sure it is a push segue between the 2 views in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

In place of where you have the view with the table, us a `UINavigationController` don't delete the view with the table, just in place of where you segue to it, or if it was the root controller, use the nav con.  Make the view with the table the root view controller of the navigation controller, and then simply use a push segue instead of a modal segue, and you should automatically get the back button

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to just use a `UINavigationController` as the parent of your table view controller, and use a push segue instead of a modal segue.

You can create two instances of `UINavigationItem` and tell the `UINavigationBar` about them by setting the bar's `items` property.  Instance 0 represents the table view controller.

You can create a `UIButton` with type 101 (the undocumented back button type), and wrap it in a `UIBarButtonItem` using `initWithCustomView:`.